# Apps Script: createTextFinder - findAll(): instead changing the format of the whole cell, how the change the format of the found text only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following function colours the whole cell when textToFind is found (within the range C5:C23):

```
function findAndSetBackgroundColor(textToFind, format){


  //Find cells that contain "ddd"
  //let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C5:C23')
    .createTextFinder(textToFind)
    .matchEntireCell(false)
    .matchCase(false)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .ignoreDiacritics(true)
    .findAll();

  //Set the background colors of those cells to yellow.
  ranges.forEach(function (range) {
      range.setTextStyle(format);
    });
}
```

Imagine we have on the range C5:C23:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First thing | row |
| Second thing | row |

As `matchEntireCell` is set to `false`, if `textToFind` is `Second`, then the whole cell `Second thing` will be formatted according with the param `format`

**But I'd like to format the word found only, not the whole cell.**

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the text of `textToFind` is included in the cells "C5:C23", you want to set the text style to only the text of `textToFind`.

In this case, how about the following modification? I thought that in this case, when `getRichTextValues()`, searching the texts, and `setRichTextValues()` are used instead of TextFinder, the script and process might be simple.

#### Modified script:

```js
function findAndSetBackgroundColor(textToFind, format) {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C5:C23');
  const v = range.getRichTextValues().map(r =>
    r.map(c => {
      const idx = c.getText().indexOf(textToFind);
      return idx != -1 ? c.copy().setTextStyle(idx, idx + textToFind.length, format).build() : c;
    })
  );
  range.setRichTextValues(v);
}
```

- In this modified script, for example, when `textToFind = "sample"` and `format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("red").build()` are used, the font color of `sample` of "C5:C23" is changed to red color.

### Added:

From your following reply,

> but I found the unexpected issue that when textToFind is too short (like one letter: "a"), then individual letters are underlined (and the wanted result is whole words). Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/TU9Me.png (trying to code a solution for that now)

> Example of string: hello ab abcedario. textToFind: ab. Unwanted result: hello a͟b͟ a͟b͟cedario. Desired result (format whole words only): hello a͟b͟ abcedario.

> The simplest solution could be adding spaces before and after textToFind. So instead searching for ab, search for: `ab`

As one more sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function findAndSetBackgroundColor(textToFind, format) {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C5:C23');
  const v = range.getRichTextValues().map(r =>
    r.map(c => {
      const r = new RegExp(`\\b${textToFind}\\b`, "g");
      const idx = [...c.getText().matchAll(r)];
      if (idx.length > 0) {
        c = c.copy();
        idx.forEach(e => c.setTextStyle(e.index, e.index + textToFind.length, format));
        return c.build();
      }
      return c;
    })
  );
  range.setRichTextValues(v);
}
```

- In this modification, for example, when there is a value of `hello ab abcedario ab abcedario`, the text style is reflected in 2 values of `ab` of `ab`.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: The code works perfect, but I found the unexpected issue that when textToFind is too short (like one letter: "a"), then individual letters are underlined (and the wanted result is whole words). Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU9Me.png (trying to code a solution for that now)

Comment: @chelder About your new issue of `The code works perfect, but I found the unexpected issue that when textToFind is too short (like one letter: "a"), then individual letters are underlined (and the wanted result is whole words). Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/TU9Me.png (trying to code a solution for that now)`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new issue. I apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detail of your new issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Example of string: `hello ab abcedario`. textToFind: `ab`. Unwanted result: `hello a͟b͟ a͟b͟cedario`. Desired result (format whole words only): `hello a͟b͟ abcedario`.

Comment: The simplest solution could be adding spaces before and after textToFind. So instead searching for `ab`, search for: ` ab `

Comment: @chelder Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: WOW! You have amazing coding skills. It seems to work perfectly now. Thanks so much for your generous piece of code for me!!! :)

Comment: @chelder Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your new issue was resolved. Thank you, too.